# Are the sound effects relevant for the strategy in Plague Inc. Evolved?

Tags: plague-inc-evolved

When playing Plague Inc. Evolved with sound effects on, you can hear random effects from time to time like an announcement on a plane or someone sneezing.

I know that there are certain events communicated through the news feed that affect the current szenario like rapid global warming or the use of air filters in planes. You have to react accordingly to optimize your plague for the new situation.

Do those sound effect also indicate such changes? E.g. would it be a good idea to evolve sneezing when I hear someone sneeze because it's currently more effective? Or are these just random effects without influence on the game?